# Create a new column based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In a column i have numbers and alphabets

| Name | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | 2 |
| Second | A1 |
| Three | 4 |
| Yellow | B2 |

The output will be

| Name | col2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2 | B |
| Second | A1 | A |
| Three | 4 | D |
| Yellow | B2 | B |

The new column should give values as if col2 = numbers the result values is from A to Z
if col2 = A1 to A222 then result = A and if col2 = B2 then result = B

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below :

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

d = {str(i): l for i,l in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, start=1)}

df["Result"] = (
    df["col2"].str.extract("([A-Z])", expand=False).fillna(df["col2"]).replace(d)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     Name col2 Result
0   First    2      B
1  Second   A1      A
2   Three    4      D
3  Yellow   B2      B
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Timeless when i tried it returns Error


  Cell In[54], line 2
    ​
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+200B

Comment: Cell In[54], line 2
    ​
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+200B

Comment: That's a problem of *copy/paste* from Jupyterlab. I fixed it. Can you try again ?

Comment: Great, It is working now what was the issue